# Retrieve information from database in OpenCart without using MVC

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

In OpenCart, given the correct database hostname, user name, password, and database name, how can I run a mysqli query to retrieve a row of information from the database in an entirely separate PHP script?  For example, if I have a php file called "my_script.php" which contains the following:

```
$order_id = '123';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_password', 'db_name');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_id = ".$order_id, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

echo $result['firstname'];
```

The goal here is to simply echo the customer's first name from Order # 123, but I get a "500 Internal Server Error" instead, so obviously something isn't communicating properly. Essentially I'm trying to completely bypass OpenCart's M/V/C structure here and just retrieve information from the DB, using the proper credentials. Is this even possible?

Opencart is the latest version, 2.3.0.2

Comment: Question, if you comment the mysqli code, and just echo the order id....or if you comment all the code and just do a simple `echo "Hello Wold";` do you still get the error 500?

Comment: No, I can echo the order id or whatever else, it's only when the $result = $mysqli->query... part is uncommented do I get the error. 

When I have it conditionally echo $mysqli->error, the actual error I get when I browse to the page "admin/my_script.php?order_id=123" is "Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: I have an idea.... instead of this: `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_id = ".$order_id, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);` just use this: `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_id = ".$order_id);`

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with the following, which I can use as a function anywhere:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_password', 'db_name');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$getresult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_id = '".$order_id."'");
if($getresult){

    $result = $getresult->fetch_array();
    $getresult->close();

} else echo($db->error);

// close the connection
$db->close();

return($result);
```